# Stuck while XML c# parsing

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, monodevelop

I have written a code in C# to parse the data from an XML file (Monodevelop). I used (using System.Xml) and (namespace).It gives an error in the (using System.Xml) The type and namespace name "Xml" does not exist in the namespace. I am new to programming. So , Kindly help me what should I do ?

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ReadXMLfromFile
{
   class sample
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("sample.xml ");
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
            case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(">");
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each
                element.
                    Console.WriteLine (reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the
                element.
                    Console.Write ("</" + reader.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(">");
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: **Show us** the code and a sample XML !

Comment: If you are using Monodevelop and compiling against Mono you shouldn't be using System.Xml but the Mono equivelent.

Comment: What is the System.Xml equivalent for the Monodevelop ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you added a reference to the assembly System.Xml in the project file (Folder References)?

Comment: Yes , I have added the System.Xml in the project file and debug folder as well. :S

Comment: I made the project in the Dektop and pasted the library in the project and bin as well as in the debug folder.